# Glass Glazing Requirement!

Tags: glass, glazing

Can a glazing guru confirm the requirement for safety glazing since there is no permanent barrier between the picture-single pane glass and the double door, approx. 4 inches between the doors jamb and the glass.. Can I use a film to add a layer of safety, rather than replacement of the entire glass? .. Built early 1970' s California
[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix here ?   What do you mean "no permanent barrier between the picture-single pane glass and the double door" there IS structure there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two issues that are required to be changed and are NOT covered by any “grandfathered clause”: 1) smoke detectors for sleeping rooms, and 2) safety glass within 18” of a floor (ICC R308.4.3) or 24” of a door (R308.4.2)

The Code says “safety glass”, not cover plate glass with film.

Look near the corners of the glass to see if there is an inscription indicating it’s tempered glass or laminated safety glass (like what’s in cars).  If none, then it’s not safety glass.